# tmux notify when someone write me on Irssi

Tags: tmux, notifications, irssi

I'm successfully using Irssi inside tmux to manage my chats. I've also tried the great [tmux-powerline](https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline), which seems really full-featured.

Now, I'm wondering if there is a method to make tmux notify me when someone sends me a message in the Irssi window in tmux.

Comment: I think someone could modify this [irssi notifications](http://code.google.com/p/irssi-libnotify/source/browse/notify.pl) script to make the `notify` sub send a tmux notification.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an irssi plugin called [hilightnotify.pl](http://510x.se/notes/posts/Tray_icon_notifications_for_irssi/).

The script runs a configurable command when `hilight` status is set/removed within irssi. I use it to execute a blinking tray icon when my name is mentioned and kill the icon when `hilight` status is removed (meaning that I have noted the message), as described in the linked article and the script itself, but one can run what one wants. If the tmux function you are after supports a CLI trigger, it is probably trivially adaptable to your situation.

Comment: Sure, I've seen it, and seems useful, I'll bind it with a Bash script :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation except I use mcabber instead of irssi.  Since you use tmux-powerline, you might be able to do something like this.

I customized mcabber to write incoming messages to ~/tmp/mcabber.out and then I created an mcabber segment in ~/etc/tmux-powerline/segments/mcabber:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

segment_path=$(dirname $0)
source "$segment_path/../lib.sh"

echo $(roll_stuff "$(cat ~/tmp/mcabber.out)" 100 1)

exit 0
```

Of course I created an entry in my status-left:

```
declare -A mcabber
mcabber+=(["script"]="${segments_path}/mcabber")
mcabber+=(["foreground"]="colour1")
mcabber+=(["background"]="colour0")
mcabber+=(["separator"]="${default}")
register_segment "mcabber"
```

I name the window that contains mcabber to 'chat'.  To mark a message as read I look at the output of $(list-windows) and see if that chat window is active in ~/bin/mcabber_mark_read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 5
# check to see that among the tmux windows, the active one is called 'chat'
tmux list-windows | grep chat | grep -q '(active)$'
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    rm ~/tmp/mcabber.out
fi
```

In my .tmux.conf I use the status bar to run ~/bin/mcabber_mark_read whenever I change window:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format '[#(~/bin/mcabber_mark_read)#I:#W#F]'
```

I don't program in perl nor do I use irssi, but with a few minutes of reading the man pages and using the googles, I might have a solution that'll work for irssi; **NB that this is untested**:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.irssi/scripts/autorun
$ cp /usr/share/irssi/scripts/msg-event.pl ~/.irssi/scripts/autorun/msg-event.pl
```

and then I edited msg-evnt.pl to look like this:

```
use Irssi;
use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION %IRSSI);

sub event_msg {
    my ($server, $data, $nick, $host) = @_;
    open(MYFILE, '>', '~/tmp/mcabber.out');
    print MYFILE $text;
    close(MYFILE)
}

#Irssi::signal_add('event privmsg', 'event_msg');
Irssi::signal_add('event pubmsg', 'event_msg');
```

I'm not sure whether you want to be notified of all or just private messages, so chose appropriately.

Comment: it seems very useful, thanks. now I'm wondering 1) how to write incoming messages in a outfile in IRSSI 2) how your solution handles read messages: it still shows the latest message even if it has been read?